# Command+Tab switches windows in Mac OS rather than the ones inside Amazon WorkSpaces

Tags: keyboard, catalina, spaces, application-switcher, aws

I  have latest Amazon WorkSpaces installed which I use to connect to my client desktop.

I previously had Windows machine. There, if I was inside Amazon WorkSpaces and I pressed Alt+Tab, I was able to switch between windows opened inside my Amazon WorkSpaces.

I have now got Macbook, and here when I am inside Amazon WorkSpaces and I press Command+Tab, it switches between windows opened in my Mac OS and not windows in my Amazon WorkSpaces.

How can I get the behavior similar to Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: Apparently, within Amazon WorkSpaces, you can use <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to emulate the Windows key command.

On macOS, <kbd>command</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> switches between applications, not windows. To cycle through the windows of the current application, use <kbd>command</kbd> and **<kbd>`</kbd>**, usually next to Z(or below escape on some keyboards). To cycle through Tabs within a window, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Amazon WorkSpaces is a desktop on demand service. So I am accessing a Windows machine via it. `command + \`` didn't work. But your suggestion gave me an idea. I tried to `option + tab` inside Amazon WorkSpaces and it worked. If you can edit your answer include this, I will happy to accept this answer.